# way to identify whether its a router or a system that im pinging to in a network

Tags: network-programming

is there any way to identify whether its a  router or a system that I’m pinging to is in a network ? as I’m doing a project "network mapping" in c#. I would like to graphically show the router and the systems that are connected, can any one help me in this. 
thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think there is, as I don't think there's a proper way to address all the computers behind a given router, unless this router has such built-in functionality. From a network point of view, if I remember well my former lessons, a router is actually a "system" as you call it, as any computer with 2 network interfaces could be set up as a router.

Answer (score 0):

You could send an SNMP request to get it to identify itself, but I'm not aware there is anything there that distinguishes routers from any other kind of IP host. They're all IP hosts.